# How do I set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG value in pipenv python?

Tags: command-line, python, environment-variables, virtualenv, pipenv

I am running python 3.6 in a pipenv shell. I want to set the value of this python environment variable `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG` to `1` without affecting my user environment variables that are outside of the pipenv shell. How do I make this setting?

Answer (score 0):

#### in a shell

```
export PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1
```

Yes?

Perhaps you are wondering how to do this *only when* in a pipenv environment from a shell?
Assuming a bash shell, detect when in a pipenv environment by checking `PIPENV_ACTIVE`

```
if [ "${PIPENV_ACTIVE+x}" == '1' ]; then
    export PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1
fi
```

#### .env file

A different approach is to use a [`.env` file](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/docs/advanced.rst#-automatic-loading-of-env).  Create such a file in your project directory with contents

```
PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1
```

Comment: Yes. Yes. Which file should I write this instruction to?

Comment: @SunBear I updated the answer.  Vote the answer if it's useful.